# How to Access Elements in a List that is Contained in a Map?

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I am attempting to access some elements stored in a list that is contained in a map. The keys in the map are doubles. The list I am attempting to access contains both a double and a map. The code below is my attempt to get a double stored in the list, as well as accessing a map contained in the list. There are 3 errors in the code below that I do not know how to solve. Any help would be great thanks.

```
private Map<Double,List<Object>> prediction = new HashMap<Double,List<Object>>();

// previous is a double that the user inputs

if(prediction.containsKey(previous)){
        List<Object> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        l1.add(0,(double)l1.get(0)+1.0); // add double 1 at index 0
        Map<Double,Double> m2 = new HashMap<Double,Double>();
        l1.add(m2); // add map to list at index 1
        prediction.put(previous,l1);
}
public double predict(double value){ 

    if (prediction.containsKey(value)){
        double total = prediction.get(value).get(0); //ERROR can't convert Object to double
        Map items = prediction.get(value).get(1); //ERROR can't convert Object to Map           
        for (double i=0; i<=items.size();i++){ //iterate through Map
            double a = items.get(i)/total; //ERROR can't divide object by double
                    }
            }
}
```

Comment: Use `List<Double>`, not `List<Object>`.

Comment: The list contains both a double and a map.

Comment: @jjohnst: That's a definite code smell.  It sounds like it'd be a lot more effective to have a type with a `double` field and a `Map` field, rather than keeping everything in an untyped `List`.

Comment: Both the map and the double need to be stored at the same key in the prediction map though.

Comment: I suggest having an object wrapper - `Map<Double,ThisIsAClassThatHasADoubleAndAMapMember>` (just don't call it that).

Comment: You need to cast the objects in `prediction` when getting them out.  For example, `double total = (Double) prediction.get(value).get(0);' If you are widening (i.e. Object c = new Date()) no cast is needed. If narrowing (i.e. Date c = (Date) someDateObject;) the cast is needed.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prediction.get(value)` returns a `List<Object>`. So `prediction.get(value).get(0)` returns an `Object`: you need to cast it to `Double` and extract the double value:

```
double total = ((Double)prediction.get(value).get(0)).doubleValue();
```

Same with the second one: You have to cast to Map:

```
Map items = (Map)prediction.get(value).get(1);
```

And the same for the 3rd one:

```
double a = ((Double)items.get(i)).doubleValue()/total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I think you can cast the values:

```
if (prediction.containsKey(value)){
    double total = (Double) prediction.get(value).get(0);
    Map items = (Map) prediction.get(value).get(1);
    for (double i=0; i<=items.size();i++) {
       double a = ((Double) items.get(i)) / total; 
    }
}
```

But this is not very clean code style. Try to split the Map into two maps. One containing Double and one containing Maps

Comment: Yeah I was trying to avoid casting it because it is not in good form, but it does work. I will look into splitting it up. I just do not want to create a lot of objects because this code is in a loop that will run 1000's of times.